# PHP session not always created with Apache redirect

Tags: php, apache, session, redirect

I have custom error handling configured in Apache that redirects the user to a certain php script for several different error codes. Here is the configuration in the http.conf:

```
Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    ErrorDocument 400 /error/apache_error.php
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/apache_error.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/apache_error.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/apache_error.php
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/apache_error.php
```

On each of my php pages, I create a session with the current location, like so:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['redirect_url'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

The way I am testing, is by going to the page I want to create the session variable for and then I enter an invalid URI such as 192.168.1.100/invalid. Where the IP address is my local apache server.

So far I've only been testing with a 404 since it's easy to produce. Apache always redirects properly to /error/apache_error.php, but for some pages the session variable contains the expected path and for some it returns NULL when checking the contents from apache_error.php.

I want to mention that I also have a rewrite rule in http.conf to remove the php extension. I thought maybe this could be causing it somehow so I set `RewriteEngine Off` but there was no difference.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The code that _writes_ into the session, is that present in `/error/apache_error.php` as well?

Comment: I don't quite follow, but in `apache_error.php` I am not writing to `$_SESSION['redirect_url']`, I only test if it's set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out but still don't know exactly why it was happening. What ended up fixing it was changing the name of the session variable. For some reason `$_SESSION['redirect_url']` was being overwritten or destroyed.